# THREE.STLLoader is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, object, three.js, stl, load

I have been trying to load a STL model on three.js 
I keep getting  THREE.STLLoader is not a constructor on the console

this is my code:

```
  var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
   loader.load( '3dbenchy-1.stl', function ( geometry ) {
   scene.add( new THREE.Mesh( geometry ) );
   });
```

Comment: http://www.diale.org/javascript3knot.html has a simple example

Answer (score 0):

`STLLoader` is no part of the library core. You have to include the respective [file](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/loaders/STLLoader.js) separately like shown in the following example:

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_stl.html

Comment: could you please give an example of how to do this? At the moment I am doing `import * as THREE from "three";`.

Comment: In this case, you have to convert `STLLoader` to a module by yourself and import it separately.

Comment: I found how to do it like this `import * as THREE from "three";var STLLoader = require('three-stl-loader')(THREE)` - but in all honesty I don't understand why that works

Answer (score 0):

within a builded three.js there is an examples folder, inside this folder there is two folders "js" and "jsm", use jsm for ES6 modules. Do not combine js class against modules